# Open URL with a number of IDs, select values and submit

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, automation

Due to an influx of unforeseen data, I now have an overload of webforms that need to be completed.

**What's required:**

- VBScript that opens IE and navigates to a variable URL.
- If a popup appears (only appears on some of the URLs), click OK.
- Wait for webpage to load – the URL loads quickly however the JavaScript webpage is a lot slower.
- Make a selection from a drop box.
- Make another selection from a drop box.
- Click submit.

Once the form is completed it needs to go the 'next URL' and perform the same task.

Now as I mentioned at the start of this post the URL varies for each form. However its only that last part of the URL that varies. See the below example. The URL remains the same only the ID changes.

```
http://saves/GEM/wwwsci/cms_call_outcome_sts_frame.html?id=TCAWSNG19924556
```

I have a list with hundreds of id's that all need to be updated.

As mentioned earlier I have pre populated forms in the past but nothing that needs to reference to a list.

Here's something similar to what I've used in the past:

```
Dim URL
Dim IE

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Call objIE.Navigate("http://saves/GEM/wwwsci/cms_call_outcome_sts_frame.html?id=TCAWSNG19924556")  '<-- Don't know how insert id referenced from a list.

objIE.Visible = True

Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : Loop    '<-- load url
WScript.Sleep(25000) '<-- Wait for webpage JavaScript (can take 20 seconds)

'Need to press "Enter" here if a pop up occurs - Maybe .SendKeys?

IE.Document.getElementByName("oper_select10").value = "1" 'select first drop down box (not working)
IE.Document.getElementByName("oper_select6").value = "1" 'select second drop down box (not working)
IE.Document.getElementByName("I2").Click 'Submit form (not working)

WScript.Sleep(2500)
```

Then the script needs to loop but with a different ID.

I'm also curious why even the basics of selecting my dropdown box don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can call an URL with different IDs in a loop like this:

```
'read IDs from file into array
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
idList = Split(fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\input.txt").ReadAll, vbNewLine)

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
For Each id In idList
  objIE.Navigate "http://saves/GEM/wwwsci/cms_call_outcome_sts_frame.html?id=" & id
  'rest of your code goes here
Next
```

Can't help you with the rest of your code without actually seeing the HTML and JavaScript code of the page you want to process.